# Irreducible factors of finite group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

$\mathbb{Q}G$ is a group algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $G$ is a cyclic group of order $6$. Then it can be written as direct sum of $r$ distinct isomorphism types of irreducible module as it is semisimple.Now $\mathbb{Q}G \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/<x^{6} -1 >$ .$ x^{6} - 1 $ has four irreducible factors $ x-1 , x+1 , x^{2}+x+1 , x^{2}-x+1 $ . Then must be $ r= 4 $ ? What are their irreduble components?

Comment: It would be best if you were to provide your attempt at this question. Mathematics S.E. has a guideline of not answering problem statement questions, because too many of them end up being students homework. I see you use Math Overflow a lot,  and have asked many questions on the same topic spaced over 7 months, suggesting it's probably not homework, but it's best to conform to MSE policy anyway if only to set an example.

Comment: This is not a homework.  Then can I edit this question  and write probable process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb QG\simeq \mathbb Q[x]/(x^6-1)$, and $$x^6-1 = (x^3-1)(x^3+1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ and it's easy to show that the factorization is final over $\mathbb Q$. Thus by CRT, $r=4$ and $\mathbb QG$ is isomorphic to $$\mathbb Q[x]/(x-1)\oplus \mathbb Q[x]/(x+1)\oplus \mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)\oplus\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-x+1)$$